# Populate multiple tables using same userform VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using following code to transfer data from user forms (with similar question set) using command buttons to populate different cells in 15-25 separate small tables in a same worksheet as per project requirement.

As I am new to VBA coding, my approach is to repeat the following code for each table to populate cells but looking for efficient way to perform this action as all user forms with questions are same but expecting different responses for each table.

Example: Each worksheet has 15-25 tables where we need to populate each table with personal information (such as Name, age, gender, date of birth, school, city) of group of students using same user forms with same question set.

I need to know if there is a better way to write this code once only (as user forms and questions are all same) for all tables in same worksheet and populate data in different tables using table-specific command buttons.

My current code and approach is:

```
Private Sub SubmitButtonForm1_Click()
wsWorkPlan.Select
Range("B13").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
lastRow = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(lastRow + 1, 6).Value = txtQ1.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = txtQ2.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = txtQ3.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 8).Value = cmbQ4.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = cmbQ5.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = cmbQ6.Text
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitButtonForm2_Click()
wsWorkPlan.Select
Range("B55").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
lastRow = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(lastRow + 1, 6).Value = txtQ1.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = txtQ2.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = txtQ3.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 8).Value = cmbQ4.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = cmbQ5.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = cmbQ6.Text
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitButtonForm3_Click()
wsWorkPlan.Select
Range("B76").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
lastRow = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(lastRow + 1, 6).Value = txtQ1.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = txtQ2.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = txtQ3.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 8).Value = cmbQ4.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = cmbQ5.Text
Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = cmbQ6.Text
End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance for your kind help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a separate function behind userform or standard module that you have each button call passing needed parameters like cell range:

```
Private Sub SubmitButtonForm1_Click()
    Call UpdateCells("B13")
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitButtonForm2_Click()
    Call UpdateCells("B55")
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitButtonForm3_Click()
    Call UpdateCells("B76")
End Sub

Public Function UpdateCells(strCell As String)
    wsWorkPlan.Select 
    Range(strCell).Select 
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select 
    lastRow = ActiveCell.Row 
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 6).Value = txtQ1.Text 
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = txtQ2.Text 
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = txtQ3.Text 
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 8).Value = cmbQ4.Text 
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = cmbQ5.Text 
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = cmbQ6.Text
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait for help!